# Protecting the openshift origin web console from public access

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, okd

So I'm hoping someone can give me some insight in my problem.
Been googling, reading blogs/articles, checking the documentation, but can't really figure it out...

So, if I want to deploy Openshift/OKD to a VPS, doesn't matter if it's the all-in-one deployment or not: how do I secure the web console?

I was expecting that it would be possible to e.g. execute an "oc cluster up" with public-master equal to my local-ip or public ip. Then, use iptables to block access to this port publicly and use ssh port forwarding (in putty) to access the webconsole. However, apparently accessing the web-console executes some form of forwarding, which basically makes ssh port forwarding for accessing it fail. I tried with ssh port forwarding by both setting the public master to my localhost ip and my public ip of the vps: same issue, ssh port forwarding doesn't work.

What I definitely do NOT want to do, is just expose the web-console to everyone with just a username and password combination.

So what options are there to actually secure the web console for openshift for public access over the internet?

There are a lot of articles to be found online on how to deploy it, but basically they all just seem to expose the web console publicly to everyone...

Comment: Also: using the all-in-one setup in production, are there any disadvantages? (I know you only have one system, so if it goes down, everything goes down, no cluster-provided redundancy. I'm wondering about other drawbacks for using this setup in production?)

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, that is, ssh port forwarding didn't work due to web-console forwarding and redirects.

Solved it by forwarding to the same port, which seems to work:

```
ssh -L 8443:localhost:8443 -f -N user@host
```

Forwarding to different port **didn't work**:

```
ssh -L 1443:localhost:8443 -f -N user@host
```